# US Opinion Polling by State and Policy

Tags: data-request, usa, polling

I'm looking for a dataset that has a state by state breakdown of opinion polling on specific policy ideas (i.e. 'should taxes be raised' as opposed to 'how do you feel about the economy'). Most datasets I've looked through such as exit polling are too demographic focused. Additionally, most of the data on specific issues seems to focus on one issue at a time, without an easy way to scrape the data into a single dataset.